# SSO from C# ASP.NET web site to SharePoint 2010 site

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

We currently have a C# ASP.NET site where users log in to perform their day to day business needs, we have recently built the users of this site a data warehouse and OLAP cube which is accessed via a SharePoint site using the BI centre template. One of the requirements from the business is that the users should be able to access this SharePoint site via a link from the ASP.NET site without having to log in again.

I've done a little research on this subject and Secure Store Services seems to come to light quite often but from what I can see this would enable the user to link from SharePoint to the ASP.NET site.

Does anyone know how one would go about making this kind of SSO connection?

Comment: I should also note that the SharePoint site and the ASP.NET site are in different domains.

Comment: take a look at Windows Identity Foundation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351

Comment: User details in the ASP.NET site are stored within a SQL database and I need to keep things this way to enable current SSO functionality from other sites to continue to function.

What I'm looking for in essence is a means to map a user in this SQL database to an AD user, then pass them over to the SharePoint site where they'll already be authenticated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your users details are stored in SQL database, there are two scenarios:

1. Your SQL database schema is same as one used by http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx. You can configure your sharpoint site for form authentication. In that case, you can use the same cookie generated by ASP.NET for SharePoint authentication.
2. If your schema is different, you need to enable Claims Authentication and you will need to write a custom claims provider. Note that, you can even do away with simple form authentication and write your custom membership provider and role provider as well if you don't want to go claims way.

Comment: We need to use Active directory users in order to interact with an SSAS database, as such what I'm really looking for is a way to take a user who is logged into one site, match them up with an AD account, auth them and then pass them through to SharePoint... is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

two simple keywords:
SQL users in one domain to another AD mapping you need to enable claims in sharepoint 2010.
two different active directories you need ADFS V2